# Trouble exporting all data to csv file

Tags: php, laravel

In my controller I have the following function:

```
public function get_export()
{
    
 
   
    $table=DB::table('drums')
       ->join('customers','drums.CustID','=','customers.CustID')
       ->join('products','drums.ProdID','=','products.ProdID')
       ->select('drums.DrumID','drums.ProdID','products.ProdName','drums.CustID','customers.CustCompanyName')
       ->orderBy('drums.DrumID')
       ->get()
       ->toArray();
      
 
  
  
  $data = array();
   foreach($table as $row) {
     $data[] = collect($row)->toArray();
    }
    
     
   //dd($data);
    
   $file = fopen('../storage/app/downloads/drums.csv', 'w');
    
    

    
   foreach ($data as $row) {
       if (fputcsv($file,$row) === false) {
       echo "failed"; exit;   
       }
        
   }
    fclose($file);
    
    
    return response()->download("drums.csv");
    
}
```

Everything works except of the 4451 lines only 3421 are written to the drums.csv file. The foreach is executing 4451 times, I tested. I increased my php memory limit to 512M. But sill it is not outputting all lines.

Data is fine all the way to 4451. Cuts off at 3421

```
Array
(
    [DrumID] => 3421
    [ProdID] => 22002
    [ProdName] => Waste Paint Related (thinner)
    [CustID] => 3369
    [CustCompanyName] => Master Brand
)

Array
(
    [DrumID] => 3422
    [ProdID] => 23389
    [ProdName] => Waste Rags & Combustible liquid
    [CustID] => 4900
    [CustCompanyName] => Friesens Printing (Industrial Drive)
)

Array
(
    [DrumID] => 3423
    [ProdID] => 23389
    [ProdName] => Waste Rags & Combustible liquid
    [CustID] => 4900
    [CustCompanyName] => Friesens Printing (Industrial Drive)
)
```

Comment: The problem is probably in the way the tables have been joined. Please post some sample data that includes some rows that get output and some that don't, and the output you get from the sample.

Comment: Maybe you run into a timeout ... did you try to increase the `max_execution_time` and then test it again? If it is the reason, i would suggest to use Queues for this: https://laravel.com/docs/master/queues

Comment: Execution time is already 90. That should be fine.

Comment: RE: Tangentially Perpendicular  Data was added to original question.

Comment: Ok - not the JOINs then. Is there anything in the server error log?

Comment: Make sure that you arn't downloading an old file other than the new generated csv file

Comment: That was the problem, it was downloading an old file. Thanks  Med.ZAIRI

Comment: It seems it downloads the same old file only in Chrome. Caching issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after clearing File Cache in Chrome.